# How to set and get a value as public item in Xcode objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing a project that has some views. I want to set a value in first view as public variable and using this value on other forms.

For example user will set a value in a textfield in first view and then I will make a query base on this field on other views.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Delegate class (Its singleton class) to store the required data & then you can access it anywhere in your application.

OR

Create your own singleton class to manage it. Reference [link](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) to create custom singleton class

Comment: Thank you very much @Nilesh Patel. I used app delegate :)

Answer (score 1):

It's funny i'm working with this last month.. haha.. Here is what i'm using right now, this suits their purpose for me..

```
//PublicVariables.h
@interface PublicVariables : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *variableOne;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *variableTwo;

+ (PublicVariables *)sharedVariables;

@end

//PublicVariables.m
@implementation PublicVariables

static id _instance = nil;

+ (PublicVariables *)sharedVariables
{
    if (!_instance)
        _instance = [[super  allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return _instance;
}

// optional
- (void)setVariableOne:(NSString *)value
{
    self.variableOne = value;
}

@end
```

Using it will be something like this: `NSString *varOne = [PublicVariables sharedVariables].variableOne;`

i suggest you import that `PublicVariables.h` inside `[ProjectName]-Prefix.pch` file.. 
 Good luck to you.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with the prepareForSegue-method of UIViewController

More information here : [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:

Comment: thank you @Maik639 , i mean define and get global variable.sorry for my mistake